# После ввода команды в терминал ничего не происходит

Tags: golang, docker, docker-compose

После ввода команды (go env -w GOINSECURE=«имя проекта») в терминал ничего не происходит, в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Что должно происходить? Какой модуль вы устанавливаете, какой go-proxy пользуетесь?